# iPhone:Fetch data from core data sorted according to index

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

Fetch data from core data  sorted according to index

In core data entity i have a field index which have index (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,......)

I want to fetch data from core data according to that index but i am unable to do that

I am not able to properly set  sortdescriptor

Anyone Please help with some code snippet

Comment: Check out the Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To tell the fetch request to sort your data...

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"myEntity"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"index" ascending:YES];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
```

Now when you fetch, the data will be sorted according to the index field.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*!
@param <NSManagedObject> array 
@return <NSManagedObject> sortedarray
*/
+ (NSArray *) sortManagedObjectArrayByObjectID:(NSArray *) array {

    NSArray *compareResult = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSManagedObject *obj1, NSManagedObject *obj2) {

        NSString *s = [obj1.objectID.URIRepresentation lastPathComponent];
        NSString *r = [obj2.objectID.URIRepresentation lastPathComponent];
        return [s compare:r];

    }];

    return compareResult;

}
```